# MySQL does not use the primary key inside a SELECT ... ORDER BY query. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `maillog` (
  `Id` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Test',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Now, I want to execute this query - but it's very slow for many rows:

```
SELECT Id FROM `maillog` ORDER BY `Id`;
```

Why does MySQL not use the primary key?

If I run `EXPLAIN` for this query, the result shows a `NULL` value for `Key`:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT Id FROM `maillog` ORDER BY `Id`;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | maillog | NULL       | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

But the `DESCRIBE` query for this table, shows the `Key` `PRI` for the `Id` column:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE `maillog`;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id    | varchar(200) | NO   | PRI | Test    |       |
| email | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: MySQL should be using the primary key for this query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I agree with you - but it doesn't work in different MySQL versions.

Comment: Edit the question and insert the `explain`.  MySQL uses a primary key as a clustered index, so it might not be obvious in the explain that the key is being used.  The "long time" for many users may simply be due to the volume of data being processed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very strange you set a primary key empty string as default.
Even i do not understand how mySql allows it.
Try to quit default value, primary key must be mandatory.

Comment: Same problem, if I set a defaul value.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Empty string or 'Test', it is the same thing, an identifier ought to be unique. I am not sure this solve the question, but i am sure is wrong. You can not open the door to a identifier does not identify a record.

Comment: you can use a default, even if not every DB support it I think. the use case is when you make insert in two step : insert with `tmp` default ID (will throw a PK violation if another is inserted) generate the ID/retrieve it, and `update set id='new id' where id='tmp'`

Comment: Everyone is free to solve problems as better thinks. Relational logic is sacred to me. I never would do that, by conceptual reasons.

Comment: I Didn't say it was a good thing, but sometime you find yourself against thing you can't solve as you would like, then maybe a default value on a PK could help you (I never used one for now)

Answer (score 0):

You have **only 1 row** in your DB, the query engine don't bother loading the index, it just make a sequential read on the table, so yes "no index".

try adding a few more row, this should change (1 line in maillog, 2 in maillog2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cac94d/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
explain SELECT Id FROM `maillog` ORDER BY `Id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cac94d/1/0)**:

```
| id | select_type |   table |   type | possible_keys |    key | key_len |    ref | rows |  Extra |
|----|-------------|---------|--------|---------------|--------|---------|--------|------|--------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE | maillog | system |        (null) | (null) |  (null) | (null) |    1 | (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
explain SELECT Id FROM `maillog2` ORDER BY `Id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cac94d/1/1)**:

```
| id | select_type |    table |  type | possible_keys |     key | key_len |    ref | rows |       Extra |
|----|-------------|----------|-------|---------------|---------|---------|--------|------|-------------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE | maillog2 | index |        (null) | PRIMARY |     202 | (null) |    2 | Using index |
```

Comment: I have the same problem with a "real" table with more than 100.000 rows.

Comment: @Tahtu could you show us the 100k row explain ? because it really look like the case I explain...

Comment: I can't - I don't have that table - I ask for a friend.

Comment: Well as this seem the only explanation and I could not reproduce your bug, we'll have to wait for the real explain (ping me with a @comment when you have it)

Comment: I received this answer (bad formated): "1SIMPLEmaillogALL1537005Using filesort" (MySQL 5.5)

Comment: @Tahtu can't read it like that... but it seem he don't use the same query/schema as you (the `ALL` should not be here, same with `filesort`...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142410/discussion-between-tahtu-and-blag).